# Does all WSL data/memory fall under the same parent directory?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to know whether all WSL memory/data is located under the same parent directory. This data would include all deb package installations in addition to the main WSL installation. For example, I was able to locate a single WSL parent directory on my machine which accounts for ~1.4GB: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`

Would this be the only WSL directory?

The reason I ask is to determine the total size taken up by WSL, not sure if there's a `bash command` which would be more convienient than my approach.

Is there any difference regarding this between WSL 1 and WSL 2?

Comment: Please clarify if you are talking about WSL 1 (1909 or earlier) or WSL 2 (2004 or greater).

Comment: @Ramhound I am running WSL 1